# How to set TargetContrlID in ModalPopupExtender with a control in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

How can I set `TragetContriID` to a `HyperLink` that is inside a `GridView`?

I tried this :

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
                        PopupControlID="Panel1" 
                        CancelControlID="btnCancel" 
                        OnCancelScript="HideModalPopup()"
                        TargetControlID="GridView1$HyperLink1">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

But I have an error: that there is no `GridView1$HyperLink1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting the `TargetControlID` of the `ModalPopupExtender` basically trigger the client side Show function of that ModalPopup when the control is clicked. So you need to wire up the controls yourself.

First, since the `ModalPopupExtender` need a `TargetControlID`, you should add a dummy control to link the modal popup to :

```
<asp:Button runat="server" 
            ID="HiddenTargetControlForModalPopup" 
            style="display:none"/>
```

And link the `ModalPopupExtender` `TargetControlID` to it

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
                        PopupControlID="Panel1" 
                        CancelControlID="btnCancel" 
                        OnCancelScript="HideModalPopup()"  
                        TargetControlID="HiddenTargetControlForModalPopup">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

So the `ModalPopupExtender` now has a target that do nothing. Now we now need to do the target's job. You need a javascript function to show the ModalPopup from client side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var ModalPopup='<%= ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID %>';

     function ShowModalPopup() {
         //  show the Popup     
         $find(ModalPopup).show();
     }
</script>
```

Then you should map the `OnClientClick` event of the control in your `gridview` to this javascript function. From your code, I see that you use a `asp:HyperLink`, I don't think it support the `OnClientClick` event, so you probably need to switch it to a `asp:LinkButton`.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
                OnClientClick="ShowModalPopup()" />
```

Comment: Hi I am using your code, but I am getting an error.. Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: handler

Comment: works fine for me, well tested solution. Your error might be somewhere else. Try to debug it to see where the error occurs.

Comment: some how got the error fixed. but It is not triggering Pop up(Message Box).

Comment: @software Well, if that helped you, an up-vote on both the question and this answer would be appreciated.

Comment: This is great, I just seem to get a postback though when I click the new button so the popup works but then page gets reloaded...  AutoPostBack property doesn't seem to be available, any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: @ebooyens If you get a postback when you click the button, you did something wrong. You could try to test it in an isolated page.

Comment: @DavRob60 I think it's being caused by the Command Buttons in my Gridview, need to retain these so still trying to figure out if I can make another plan

Comment: @DavRob60 It seems placing the Gridview inside an UpdatePanel but keeping the pop-up outside of it does the trick